# Why “apply for universities” is not ok, but “apply for college” and “apply to college/universities” are ok?

Tags: word-meaning

I have a theory.

First, we say "to a place" and "for a reason".

The term "University" typically refers to an institution, a place.

The term "college" can refer to a specific institution, a place; for example, "college" is often used to refer to undergraduate education within a university, or a standalone college that is not part of a larger university.

But "college" can also refer to a general term for higher education. This usage likely stems from the fact that many students begin their higher education journey at the undergraduate level (college level), so the term “college” has become synonymous with post-secondary education in general.

When someone says they are "applying for college,"  "college" refer to higher education in general.

Comment: Who told you "apply for universities" is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-secondary education, the general idea
In the UK, attend or **go to university** (even when it is made up of colleges) is a general idea and, in the US even when the university is a college (Harvard College) or is a university with various colleges as part of it, one says **go to college**.

So, to repeat this, as **a general rule**, it's like this:
UK=go to university Meaning: tertiary education (post-secondary education
US=go to college Meaning: tertiary education (post-secondary education)

UK: Did you go to university? [Yes, I went to [x]
US: Did you go to college? [Yes, I went to [x]

**And in the UK and US**, we say: **apply to** university or college

But **apply *for* a grant or scholarship** in both places.

You apply for something that is given or granted to you.

[Apologies to other English-speaking countries, which are not covered here. Each country can have its own specificity.]

Answer (score 2):

This might be yet another case of the difference between AmE and BrE usage.
On this side of the pond it is usual to apply **to** a university or college or to apply **for** a place **at** a university or college.
In the UK a University is a place where you go to study for a bachelors or higher degree.
Some universities have multiple colleges such as Oxford, Cambridge or London. For example London has University College, King's college, Imperial College and so on.
Each major London college usually offers a full range of degrees taught on the premises. Other universities may share teaching facilities between colleges. Confusingly, some colleges don't call themselves college. The London School of Economics is part of the University of London as is the School of Tropical Medicine.

However **college** also has another meaning in the UK. Sixth form colleges are the  senior school for 16+ year olds. They teach a full range of school subjects for university entrance, vocational studies or just preparing to enter work.
To confuse matters even more, there are specialist colleges for many purposes from teacher training, a full 3 year course ending in a degree to typing where the course in keyboard skills could be as short as 6 weeks.
Then there are Institutes such as The Courtauld Institute of Art, but enough.

Comment: and the sentence "I am only applying to 2 universities" is completely valid

Comment: You got two upvotes and don't do the BrE/AmE difference. Go figure...

Comment: @Lambie That is an exercise for the student, particularly the OP who IMHO is talking more about the AmE usage of the words. I pointed out that, in the UK, college can be a place of secondary education, unlike joy2020's interpretation.

Comment: The OP doesn't know. It is our job to explain these differences.

Answer (score 0):

You apply **to** someone who assesses whether you are eligible to be admitted. You apply **for** something you want. Hence you might apply to the government for a pension, or apply to the admissions office for a specific course. With colleges and universities they normally handle their own admission so you apply to a university for a place there. So it doesn't matter if you use "to" or "for".